# Cannot Delete Item "Could Not Find This Item" issue

Tags: windows, malware-removal

A friend sent a long a file (a .rar) he wanted me to check out for him before he installed it.

I downloaded it and unrared it with no problems, but it was full of .exe's instead of the intended contents (fonts) so I advised him to delete it immediately and not use.

I then proceeded to do the same, but the folder simply will not delete. Oddly the files went fine, and I never ran anything, but this is what I'm seeing:

```
Could not find this item

This is no longer located in C:\Users\This_User\Desktop. verify the item's
location and try again.
```

I've tried the following things with no help:

- Using "Unlocker" to Unlock and delete
- Using move on reboot and rebooting
- Using PendMoves (from sysinternals) and rebooting Elevating a cmd line, doing a dir /x to get the short name of the folder, and then del 'shortna~1'
- Moving the folder to a new folder and then trying to delete the parent folder

I'm on Windows 7 RTM, very fresh install. Any thoughts?

**Update:** Just to confirm, I've run Hijack this and half a dozen other malware detectors, and everything came back clean (no extra processes, no other obvious badness). Rebooting in safe mode didn't help either.

Comment: Some part of the NTFS filesystem is damaged. I've had this issue. Never was able to fix it without a reformat.

Comment: if you have this issue, try [Cale's suggestion](http://superuser.com/questions/28912/cannot-delete-item-could-not-find-this-item-issue/263386#263386) - worked for me.

Comment: The problem here is that `del` doesn't work for folders. Correct syntax would be `rd shortna~1 /s` to remove the folder/subfolders/contents.

Comment: I had this exact problem (once in my life). I had to reboot in my linux and delete it from there. No matter what I did from Windows 10 it didn't worked. From Linux I could do a normal delete.

Comment: This was the folder name: "the 100 subtitles" (located on desktop) and was already empty. When looking into the security tab about the folder It was not accesible. Hope this info helps.

Comment: I did everything on this site and more for hours and nothing worked. Finally Unlocker 1.9.2 after trying to find a lock and not finding one on my files offered to delete them and it succeeded. To future users, it's worth trying. Even if it didn't work for the OP. https://unlocker.en.softonic.com/

Answer (score 23):

I know you said that you tried deleting the shortname of the file and it didn't work for you, but it does work for some forms of this problem. It worked for me. So for the sake of completeness I am mentioning it here.

Step by step:

1. press windows key + r
2. type `cmd.exe`, press enter
3. `cd \to\the\folder\containing\the\problem\file`
4. `dir /x`
5. Note the short filename of the problem file. It will look for example like `BLAH~1`.
6. `del BLAH~1`

Comment: This did not work for me since I am using Windows 10, which does not save short filenames by default.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately Windows 10 shows no short filenames.

Answer (score 14):

Try the [**DelinvFile**](http://www.purgeie.com/delinv/) tool.  It worked for me perfectly when NOTHING worked before.

BR,
galmeida

Comment: this worked for me

Comment: Works great, shame it's not freeware - but anyway 3 actions are more than enough for me)

Comment: This is also worked for me when nothing else did

Comment: DelinvFile is working perfectly.  Tested it with Windows 10

Comment: Worth mentioning that DelinvFile worked after everything else failed. The problem was so bad it caused blue screens during previous deletion attempts. So, definitely try it.

Answer (score 7):

Boot into a Linux live CD environment and delete it with NTFS-3G?

Answer (score 6):

Ah ha!!! I did it!!! This was so annoying but after several hours... it dawned on me. Basically, you make a folder with the same name as the missing folder, then you drag the folder into the folder with the missing folder. Windows did not ask me to combine the folders, but after that, Windows knows where the folder is and you can delete it. I didn't try to copy and pasted I'm guessing that would work too.

Comment: This solution works on Windows 7. Please post if it works on previous versions.

Comment: Genius! this works! I had the same problem after extracting a zip file (from Program Files\Visual Studio) into my user\downloads folder. It resulted in a weird folder containing files I couldn't access or delete. I followed this advice, Win 7 asked me to merge which I said yes to, and then it let me delete the folder with no fuss.

Comment: didn't work for me - I then somehow had 2 identically named folders in alongside eachother!

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me :

```
1. press windows key + r
2. type cmd.exe, press enter
3. rd /s "\\?\D:\bad\folder\path "
```

Notice the space at the end of `"\\?\D:\bad\folder\path "`

Comment: This works for files that have bad characters in their name or are too long. I had files created by a linux server that windows was unable to delete by name. And in Powershell: `Remove-Item -Recurse -Force "\\?\E:\Folder\Path\"` with no space.

Comment: Interesting. For some reason `rd /s "badFolder"` did not work but `rd /s "\\?\D:\badFolder"` *did* work. Does anyone know why this is? What's with that question mark?

Answer (score 2):

Isn't there a special character in the name of the directory? Like an "empty" character that looks like a space but is not a space?

Have you tried a "Check Disk", as the directory entry for that directory or its parent might be corrupted?

Comment: no special characters. check disk reports nothing.

Comment: I have the same problem. In my case it is a space character that follows the folder name.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the folder is actually empty? There could be a file marked Hidden and Read-Only, or System in there. Windows could be blocking you from deleting because of the Hidden+RO or System file.

Haven't got a Windows 7 machine handy here, but in Vista you'd make sure that you can see all the files by opening Explorer, clicking "*Organize*",  selecting "*Folder and Search Options*", then clicking the "*View*" tab. If you scroll down that screen you would see a "*Hidden files and folders*" option, make sure they're shown, then scroll down a little more to where it says "*Hide protected operating system files*" and make sure that isn't selected.

Now have a look at the folder and see if there's anything more in it.

Alternatively open a command window in the folder and type `attrib` see if any files show up (probably with SH or HR flags set on them).

Comment: Nope, nothing there.

Answer (score 0):

Before you do anything else, run some anti-virus and malware tools to make sure your machine is not infected with anything. You did open an unknown or possible untrusted rar.

[Clean up infected computer from viruses](https://superuser.com/questions/23633/clean-up-infected-computer-from-viruses)

https://superuser.com/questions/20895/best-adware-removing-software-thats-free

Comment: Will do.... but can [mal|ad]ware spread just by extracting an archive? Not by running anything, just extracting?

Comment: Was it a self-extracting rar? If so, those could potentialy be dangerous.

Comment: Nope, just used "ExtractNow" to expand it, and that was it. No joy on the anti-malware tool... nothing found, and it's still undeletable.

Comment: What happened when a current virus scanner looked at the files in that rar?

Comment: Unfortunately, deleted the archive when it was clear it was filled with badness.

Answer (score 0):

Safe Mode is also something to try. That or if it's already too late, see if you can identify the process name, and use Hijack This to get rid of it.

Comment: it doesn't appear to be a process of any kind. and nothing is coming up on malware.

Comment: Safe mode didn't help - Hijack this didn't report anything.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if Windows 7 has Command Prompt. But you can delete it from Command Prompt. Go to the said directory and then use the command `del` against the file name.

1. Go to Command Prompt "Windows + R"
2. `cd C:\Users\This_User\Desktop`
3. `del "filename.abc"`

This should work.

Comment: It's not a file, it's a directory - and as mentioned command line doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Try hitting F5 after you delete.  It may be that it actually has been deleted but the view hasn't automatically refreshed.  I had the same problem.  Also newly created folders or renamed files wouldn't show up without refreshing.  Unselecting the two navigation pane checkboxes under the general tab in folder options seem to fix it.

Comment: Nope, not a refresh issue...

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that the full path of this directory is too long (>255 characters)? If so, try renaming the directory to something shorter and then deleting it.

Comment: Nope, renamed it to something short, still no go.

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem with the desktop not being able to auto refresh. Like others have said, try pressing F5 to refresh because the file may already be deleted. Here's a thread on the same problem: http://social.answers.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7desktop/thread/249f4794-13c8-4fc5-939c-b3d1fe6433fb
The problem usually has to do with some program like WinRAR that copies files onto the desktop  instead of Windows Exlporer.

Comment: Sorry, restarted, refreshed, etc many many times. No go.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, attempting to remove files I had copied across a networked bridge from an installed virtual machine.  It seemed nothing I did would remove these:  I tried the "[Take Ownership Registry Hack](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/add-take-ownership-to-explorer-right-click-menu-in-vista/)", and the even more powerful "AccessGain MiniFilter Driver" (http://www.hobeanu.com/blog/)  Which in Windows 7 64-bit requires quite a concerted effort (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa906338.aspx).  Inside the Windows 7 64-bit GUI, it seemed nothing would remove these files - I was stymied across every approach.

Finally, I reached into my quiver for an old trusted friend.

> ***The Command Prompt***

I was still booted in the "disabled driver signature enforcement session," that I mentioned above.  The "AccessGain MiniFilter Driver" (http://www.hobeanu.com/blog/accessgain-tool/)  was installed and was giving me a superuser 'God-like' control over anything on my drive.  At this point:

1. I fired up an "Administrative Rights enabled Command Prompt," (http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/enable-the-hidden-administrator-account-on-windows-vista/)
2. Navigated to my Desktop. I used the command: "cd c:\Users\superuser\Desktop"
3. *(Note: Change the term "superuser" to your account name.)*
4. Looked to see if the files were present. I used the command "dir *backup*"
5. *(Note: All my files had the word "backup" in them. If different for you, replace term)*
6. Then I simply deleted the files. I used the delete command: "del *backup*"

When all else fails, pull up your sleeves and get your hands dirty with the trusted old command prompt... Hope this helps some of you.  I was pulling my hair out on this one, and when I resolved it, thought it might be worth sharing.

Cheers!

Comment: This is interesting, but it's not a command prompt issue. I should have tried to boot into disable drive signature enforcement session.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem. using [delinv](http://www.purgeie.com/delinv/dldelinv.htm) i was able to delete the folder(s)

Answer (score 0):

This problem (folders in Windows 7 containing executable files being inaccessible) is *not* a permission issue, nor an open-handle issue. It happens when the [Application Experience service is disabled](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2503886). Set the service to manual to resolve it:

```
Run dialog (or command prompt):

  > sc config AeLookupSvc start= demand
```