# How to make sure a system is not infected by a specific trojan?

Tags: windows, virus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Computer is infected by a virus or a malware, what do I do now?](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/computer-is-infected-by-a-virus-or-a-malware-what-do-i-do-now)

In this case it's the  TR/Alureon.19456U.3 trojan. On this Antivir site it's stated to be detected:

http://www.avira.com/en/threats/section/vdfhistory/ivdf_no/7.01.05.243/7.01.05.243.html

The system in question doesn't have the symptoms (lags, Firefox crashed) either.

Is there a way to be sure the trojan is not active?

Comment: There is a more general question here: http://superuser.com/questions/23633/clean-up-infected-computer-from-viruses .

Answer (score 1):

If the AV specified has it in the database, the only way to be 100% sure would be to use that program to scan the computer in question, Or do a fresh OS install. Even the first option can be a bit flaky, as some viruses can change their characteristics dynamically by being updated via the internet or other means. A fresh install is the best way to ensure the machine is clean 100%.

Comment: +1 that's right, John, can't trust these previously infected systems :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, it showed me the virus one time, where I deleted it and all it's components. After several virusprogs including a live CD, it does not show anything like a virus anymore, also I have no problems like "lag" or firefox crashing, etc.

Is it gone? I don't know. But setting up a whole new system (fresh install) would take some time AND I don't have some passes for some progs anymore, which would again cost a lot of time to get them via phone, aso.